# Editing a question on an HTTPS site redirects you to the HTTP site

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, ssl

I haven't tested this in depth, but after doing a Suggested Edit to a topic on Gaming via HTTPS, I got redirected to the HTTP version of the question.

I only noticed this as the connection I'm on blocks the HTTP version of the site.

Comment: We don't fully/officially support SSL yet. I'd expect this to work when we do, but at at this point... yeah, that's just what it is.

Comment: As for *"the connection I'm on blocks the HTTP version of the site"*, if that's not some office firewall: any clue why non-HTTPS is blocked?

Comment: @Arjan It is an office firewall.

Comment: I can't reproduce this, although that might be because I've only tested it on sites where I have full editing privileges. (I don't want to waste reviewer time with needless edit suggestions, but I'll try to remember to test this the next time I find a legitimate edit to suggest.)